# Quickest way to get dictionary key that is closest to 1 in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key, sorting

Hi I wanted to ask if this is the quickest and taking the least resources way to get value closest to 1 in dictionary or is there better, more effective way of doing this.

```
import operator

dct = {"a": 0.1, "b": 0.2, "c": 0.7, "d": 1, "e": 0.5}

sorted_orders = sorted(dct.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
sorted_orders = str(sorted_orders.pop()[:1])
a = len(sorted_orders) - 3
sorted_orders = sorted_orders[2:a]
print sorted_orders
```

Desired output is contents of key closest to 1 here:
d

Comment: Never seen any other way of doing it natively, so someone who has would have to swoop in and save the day. But have you considered expanding your `sorted()` logic? do a manual `for key, val in dct.items():` and break whenever you find a exact match? or reverse the dictionary if possible? Let the integer be the key and the letter the value, there for you could fetch `dct[1]` if that's a possibility. Otherwise you could always use `from collections import OrderedDict` and save them in the order of magnitude. Or a simple pre-sorted list where you could do `scores[-1]` and get the highest?

Comment: @Torxed I could swap keys with values but it's not guaranteed that I'll always get 1 (that's why I want to sort values and then pop closest value to 1.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
closest = sorted(dct.values(), key=lambda x: abs(1-x))[0]
```

I sort the items with a key that gives the distance between the number and `1`.  (`abs(1-x1)`).  The first item, therefore, is the value that is closest to `1`.  You could use `min()` as in the answer by Gábor Erdős, but if you want to know the whole order, use this.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
min(list(dct.values()), key=lambda x: abs(x - 1))
```

Notes:

1. This method works for lists as well
2. This is not the most efficient
   way. A faster approach would be to use `bisect`